# when run the Flutter doctor command why it shows "Unable to find bundled Java version." and how to solve that

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Android Studio (version 2022.1) X Unable to find bundled Java version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this one and it worked for me

`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio`
then copy the content of `jbr` and paste the content into the `jre` folder
run doctor again and problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio then copy all the content of jbr and paste all that content into the jre folder.
Run flutter doctor again